# How to join tables in dynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I know DynamoDB doesn’t support joining tables, but here is my use case:

(Using similar example to hide exact details, not posting a homework problem)

I have four tables

```
Person ( unique_id(hash key), Name(range key), Age, Gender)<br>
UIDtoSIDTable ( uid(hash key) , sid)<br>
SIDtoStudentID(sid(hash key), studentID, other attributes)<br>
StudentDetails(studentID(hash key), schoolName, Grades)
```

I am using dynamodbmapper.

My application requires to display following data in a table:

```
unique_id, Name, Age (from Person table)
sid 
SchoolName, Grades (from studentDetails table)
```

Right now my implementation is:

1. scan uidtosidTable for all uid-sid pair in a list say list1
2. for each sid in list1, query for studentID from SIDtoStudentID table
3. for each uid query from Person table, and for each studentID get data from StudentDetails Table

Problem with this implementation is that it is taking very long to complete, over 5 minutes for 1000 items.

If it was a relational database I would have joined the four tables, and got the required data.

How to achieve this is dynamodb efficiently?

Comment: refer this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/EMRforDynamoDB.html

Comment: you can use Amazon EMR

Answer (score 6):

DynamoDB does not support joining tables on the service-side. Any joining you may wish to do has to be done on the client.

If possible, you should revisit your table design to include all needed information in a single record in one table instead of the 4 tables you have.

Your Dynamo DB Table would look something like this:

```
unique_id, Name, Age, Gender, studentID, schoolName, Grades, other attributes
```

If that is not possible then your only option is to try to perform the joins in memory with a combination of full table scans with indexes and  queries. For instance you could create a Global Secondary Index (GSI) to be able to do a reverse mapping for SID to UID. And then, you could use queries instead of scans to perform the joining - though the joining would still be performed on client side.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using JDBC driver for dynamodb, Example is cdata jdbc driver. I used this in my one project it worked well for joining tables as well aggregate functions. Only thing is in my case I used joining for tables with very less data (max 1000 records). For huge data you might have to check if there is any performance impact.

For below code you have register with Cdata and download the Cdata JDBC driver. following is the Cdata web url [enter link description here](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/dynamodb/jdbc/)

```
private String getLastRecordDate(DbServer dbserver, String area){
    String lastRecordDate="";
    Connection conn =null;
    try{
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:dynamodb:Other='threadcount=1';Verbosity=2;AccessKey=abcdefgc;SecretKey=acddasdd;Domain=amazonaws.com;Region=mumbai;");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

        boolean ret = stat.execute("select employee_name,project_name from employee e left join project p on e.project_id=p.id ");
        ResultSet rs=stat.getResultSet();
        if(rs.next()){
            rs.getString("employee_name");
            rs.getString("project_name");
        }
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        log.info(ex.toString());
    }finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
    }
    return lastRecordDate;
}
```

Comment: @Tiw thank you, I recently started using stackoverflow delicately. As it is very useful for all IT people.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with a single table. Each row in the table can contain the person's unique ID, name, age, gender, student ID, school name, and a collection of grades.

Comment: My question is how to create such a table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HiveQL which provides aggregate functions as well.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Querying.html